# Check if App is running on network PC

Tags: c#

I have a C# app application working to some extent. What i need to do is to continue execution if a computer (given an IP Address) is running an application (TEKBSS.exe).  How can i do that?  Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process

Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "TEKBSS.exe";
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

EDIT:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Security;

public class MainClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Process[] allProcs = Process.GetProcesses("RemoteMachineOnYourNetwork");
        foreach (Process p in allProcs) 
           Console.WriteLine("  -> {0} - {1}", p.ProcessName, p.PeakWorkingSet64);

    }
}
```

Comment: He's trying to tell if a process is already running, not start a new one (according to the original question).

Comment: @Steve
Look at the WaitForExit line. Thats what tells you that the process ends. And yes it is only a suggestion that he should start the process from c# as well...

Comment: id like to check if the application (tekbss.exe) is running lets say 172.16.32.34

Comment: The WaitForExit doesn't tell you if a process is running on a remote machine. It blocks the thread start started the process until it completes. That's very different.

Comment: @Steve
You are of course right about the WaitForExit. I assumed it could be used if the process was started from the main process.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this through [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You'll need appropriate credentials to access the remote machine.

The [System.Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms257340.aspx) namespace includes features for using WMI from C#.

Here you go:

```
        // Don't forget...
        // using System.Management; <-- Need to add a reference to System.Management, too.

        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\192.168.1.73\root\cimv2");
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name='TEKBSS.exe'";
        var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
        searcher.Scope = scope;
        bool isRunning = searcher.Get().Count > 0;
```

The scope tells WMI what machine to execute the query on, so don't forget to change the IP address accordingly.

The ManagementObjectSearcher will then query the machine for a list of all processes with the name TEKBSS.exe.

Comment: WMI is the Windows Management Interface. It's used by tools such as Systems Management Server to interrogate and manipulate machines remotely. You can use WMI to find out if a specific process is running on a remote machine - which is what you want to do. The article I linked to shows an example of doing this using VBScript, but you can call the WMI API from other languages.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28VS.85%29.aspx) to query information on remote machines, such as which programs are running.

You will need to reference `System.Management.dll`, and have appropriate rights on the remote machine to access WMI.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Management;

namespace Bling
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        const string Host = "vmhost01";
        const string Path = (@"\\" + Host + @"\root\CIMV2");
        const string Exe = "TEKBSS.exe";

        var queryString = string.Format("SELECT Name FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = '{0}'", Exe);

        var query = new SelectQuery(queryString);

        var options = new ConnectionOptions();
        options.Username = "Administrator";
        options.Password = "*";

        var scope = new ManagementScope(Path, options);

        var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

        bool isRunnning = searcher.Get().Count > 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Is {0} running = {1}.", Exe, isRunnning);
    }
}
```

Comment: the username and password is a problem for me  as the policys on our environment countrywide is such that the  remote pc's have to change the passwords every month and this is a generic program in that different parts of the country will use it to connect to different remote pc's (pc's running the Tekbss software)

Comment: @Privesh Presumably your machines are under a Windows domain(s). You would need to set up an account specifically that could access WMI information within your domain. You can finely tune which WMI information an account can access. This is a matter for a sys admin to sort out though.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is .net code. But I used this a while ago to do the same. Hopefully it will give you an idea, and I will try and convert. As long as you have permission rights you can execute the command `pushd` in your code. You can try executing from the command line first to make sure you can get in.

[PushD](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/pushd.mspx?mfr=true)

```
//pushes into the Given Machine on the C:\ and filters for your program
Dim sCommand as String = "pushd \\<MachineName>\C$ && tasklist.exe /FI ""IMAGENAME eq <NameOfExecutable>.exe""
//execute command from program
Shell("cmd.exe /c" & sCommand. AppWinStyle.Hide, True);
```

You will most likely want to execute `popd` after to return to the directory on your machine.

Let me see if I can convert to C for you. I will edit in a bit.

**EDIT**

[Link to executing commands in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Execute_Command_in_CSharp.aspx)

Comment: I would change the command to: tasklist /s MachineName /FI "IMAGENAME eq WHATEVER.exe"

Comment: eish u guys are talking greek to me, lol. Im just starting in c#